# Changing opacity on Jquery element via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the following call to AJAX to handle some data in the database. Currently the chosen row fades and the disappears altogether, but i only want it to fade, not disappear altogether. Im trying to simulate that the row has been chosen. Ideally Id like to add a 'checked' icon to the button when it has been selected, but Im unsure as to how to proceed so Im just going to fade the row for now.

Here is my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".accept").click(function(){
var element = $(this);
var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
var info = 'id=' + del_id;

 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "accept.php",
   data: info,
   success: function(){}

});
  $(this).parents(".show").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow")
  .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
});
});
</script>
```

Any help with the fade or the added icon is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First, do your fading in the callback of your AJAX call. Second, try this instead. Setting the opacity to `0.5` instead of `hide`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".accept").click(function(){
          var element = $(this);
          var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
          var info = 'id=' + del_id;

         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "accept.php",
            data: info
         }).done(function(returndata) {
              $(element ).parents(".show").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow")
              .animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, "slow");
         });
    });
});
</script>
```